# Searching for library using Project Structure yields no results

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Basically what the title says. 
If I search for any android library (e.g. support, picasso etc.), the thing on the right of the search field turns for about a second and then nothing.

I can only add the default libs you see when the dialog opens.

Is this a bug? Something to do with my network settings (manually typing in the compile statement in build.gradle works fine)? Something to do with file system permissions? I'm on a Macbook Pro.

I've tried resetting the cache and restarting Android Studio. I'm on the latest stable version (3.0.1).

Comment: Please use the exact version number instead of "latest". These question may end up sticking around for a long time and people would need to figure out which version you refer to.

Comment: edited, I assumed tags would be enough.

Comment: @AdwayMalhotra Tagging usually us enough, I think he missed that. More information is was good though.